# My desktop icons are large, and menus and background look differnet

Tags: 16.04, themes

I upgraded to 16.04 last week. After a daily update I rebooted my laptop and I found that my desktop icons look larger, my desktop wallpaper is changed to black and my menu looks classic.

I thought the problem was with Nvidia driver, so I removed it and reinstalled it, but the issue persists. Please, any idea can be helpful.

[image: desktop screenshot with icons]

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/83099/how-to-change-desktop-icon-size

Comment: Thanks a lot @David Foerster, I did reset my Unity Configuration but it does not work!!. ... I recently installed MongoDB there was a problem in its installation between upstart and systemd. Is that relating to my problem? Thanks a lot again for your kind response.

Comment: Unlikely unless it somehow created a package management problem. You can test that theory by watching whether `sudo apt-get install -f` produces any errors (and possibly fixes them).

Comment: It doesnt fix my problem. Thanks again @DavidFoerster.

Comment: By the way, when I logged in to guest account everything is fine. So, can I create another account to solve the problem and how? Thanks for any help.

Comment: If using a guest account fixes it, it must be some local config issue and a duplicate of the target I think (which answers did you try?) though maybe some updates are required to the post :S [reposting this comment which I accidentally deleted]

Answer (score 1):

I used to have a similar problem. For the black background problem and the change in Unity theme, [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/365511/497512) solve my problem:

> I finally figured out what caused this problem. At some point in time,
>   somehow I'd done something wrong with my gtk-3 settings. Remove the
>   folder via
>
> rm -r ~/.config/gtk-3.0
>
> and then logging out and in again solved my problem. Now all the themes look fine again.

Then my icons were even larger than yours, but recover the default theme configuration. I know this sounds kind of weird, but I managed to change the size of the icons by open a folder (any folder) with files inside (any type of files) and **keep pressing Ctrl + Mouse Scroll**, this change the size for all files inside and outside the folder.

Sometimes best solutions are the easiest.

Comment: +1 I never thought resizing icons from within a folder will change the desktop icon as well. That worked for me.  It makes sense since all are being browsed by the File manager.